# Django Rest Framework Permissions Conflict

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I'm having a bit of trouble with understanding the flow of Django Rest Framework authentication and permission.  My `REST_FRAMEWORK` dict in `settings.py` is as follows:

```
# Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
# or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
],

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
#     # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
#     # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
```

I now am trying to make it so that only authenticated users can make the `users-list` or `users-detail` calls, but I do need unauthenticated users to be able to make calls to `users-create`.  I have tried the following using [`rest_condition`](https://github.com/caxap/rest_condition):

```
from rest_condition import Or, And, Not
class UserViewSet(ListOnlyIfAdminMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = U.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    # Would this permission_classes declaration come before or be overridden by
    #   the decorator below?
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAdminOrTargetUser,]

    @permission_classes([Or(Not(IsAuthenticated), IsAdminUser)])
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         # stuff
```

But when I try to make a `POST` request to `/api/users` with the right information to create a new user, I get back the following:

```
{
detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Now, obviously authentication credentials couldn't be provided, because the user doesn't have an account or token yet.  What's the way to enable a user to sign up without already requiring credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#setting-the-permission-policy) you can see the order of setting a permission for a certain method.

So you can see that you are on the right path with setting the permissions only for the *create* function. However, I don't see why you need to do a rest_condition for your permission: a simple **Not(IsAuthenticated)**, to override the default settings, would suffice.

Comment: Rereading the docs, it sounds then like the method-level permissions can only be **more restrictive** than the view-level permissions--which is what I think I was struggling with.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be right. So the right way to go about this would probably be to set the permissions for each method, according to your needs.

Comment: Or you can use a custom permissions class for your view: if the request method is POST (mapped to create) allow for any users; otherwise, allow only for authenticated users which own the account or admins. [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#custom-permissions)

Comment: I ended up writing a meta-meta class that generates meta classes that I would assign to the Viewset in question to decorate the method functions with permission functions I pass in on declaration.  Complex, but excellent user interface and works perfectly.

Comment: Is it also true that object and view-level permissions can only be more restrictive than global permissions defined in `settings.py`? I kept on getting an error until I commented out the permissions so I could define them per-view and per-object.

Comment: There seems to be nothing in the docs that would imply such a behaviour. View-level permissions should overwrite global permissions, whether they are more or less permissive. What is the error that you are getting?